# google-coud-storage python list_blobs performance

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I have a very simple python function:

```
def list_blobs(bucket, project)
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=project)
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='basepath/', max_results=999999,
                              fields='items(name,md5Hash),nextPageToken')
    r = [(b.name, b.md5_hash) for b in blobs]
```

The blobs list contains 14599 items, and this code takes 7 seconds to run.
When profiling most of the time is wasted reading from the server (there are 16 calls to page_iterator._next_page.

So, how can I improve here? The iteration code is deep in the library, and the pointer to each page comes from the previous page, so I see no way on how to fetch the 16 pages in parallel so I can cut down those 7 seconds.

[image: Profile from SnakeViz]

I am on python 3.6.8,

```
google-api-core==1.7.0
google-auth==1.6.2
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-storage==1.14.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.6
protobuf==3.6.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `max_results=999999` is larger than 14599 - the number of objects, forcing all results into a *single* page. From [`Bucket.list_blobs()`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.list_blobs):

> Parameters:
>
> **max_results** (int) – (Optional) The maximum number of blobs in each page of results from this request. Non-positive values are ignored.
>   Defaults to a sensible value set by the API.

My guess is that the code spends a lot of time blocked waiting for the server to provide the info needed to iterate through the results.

So the 1st thing I'd try would be to actually iterate through multiple pages, using a `max_results` smaller than the number of blobs. Maybe 1000 or 2000 and see the impact on overall duration?

Maybe even trying to use the multiple pages explicitly, using `blobs.pages`, as suggested in the deprecated `page_token` property doc (emphasis mine):

> **page_token** (str) – (Optional) If present, return the next batch of blobs, using the value, which must correspond to the `nextPageToken`
>   value returned in the previous response. **Deprecated: use the `pages`
>   property of the returned iterator instead of manually passing the
>   token**.

But I'm not quite sure how to force the multiple pages to be simultaneously pulled. Maybe something like this?

```
[(b.name, b.md5_hash) for page in blobs.pages for b in page]
```

Comment: I'll do some testing on those suggestions and see if it improves. It is already calling _next_page 16 times so I guess that means it is reading 16 distinct pages so my max_results is quite being ignored (it looks like I'm getting 1000 results per page more or less).

Comment: Did you work it out? did the `blobs.pages` thing work?